# Loopback model definition is not adding foreign key relation in database table

Tags: loopbackjs

I am using loopback for API design and data modeling. I am using MySQL as my database. Although my API rest URL successfully returns results e.g. `/states/{id}/cities`. I have following model but it seems no foreign key relation is added. Following are my model definition.

```
"state": {
  "options": {
    "relations": {
      "cities": {
        "type": "hasMany",
        "model": "city",
        "foreignKey": "stateId"
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "public": true,
  "dataSource": "db",
  "plural": "states"
},
"city": {
  "options": {
    "relations": {
      "state": {
        "type": "belongsTo",
        "model": "state",
        "foreignKey": "stateId"
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "public": true,
  "dataSource": "db",
  "plural": "cities"
}
```

and below is screenshot of city table. 
[image]

And following is State table screenshot.
[image]

I may be doing it wrong here. Looking forward for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems Loopback handles relations in models using "WHERE" query and not based on relations.
Following are details.

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/16

Comment: Does it have any impact on performance when querying ? And why would you need the foreign keys ?

Answer (score 3):

`loopback-mysql-connector` **DOES SUPPORT** adding foreign keys to MySQL DB using `automigrate` and `autoupdate` combined with `foreignKeys` key in model definition filse. But people didn't aware of this feature due to their lack of documentation.

They updated document after [my discussion](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql/issues/294) with them. Please check again their README: https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-connector-mysql#auto-migration

Simply put, your code should be:

**bin/automigrate.js**

```
var path = require('path');

var app = require(path.resolve(__dirname, '../server/server'));
var ds = app.datasources.db;
ds.autoupdate(null, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Finished migration');
  ds.disconnect();
});
```

**common/models/book.json**

```
{
  "name": "Book",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }, "isbn": {
      "type": "string"
    },
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {
    "author": {
      "type": "belongsTo",
      "model": "Author",
      "foreignKey": "authorId",
      "primaryKey": "id"
    }
  },
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {},
  "foreignKeys": {
    "authorId": {
      "name": "authorId",
      "foreignKey": "authorId",
      "entityKey": "id",
      "entity": "Author"
    }
  }
}
```

Then run migration script to create / update DB tables (they will have foreign keys):

```
node bin/automigrate.js
```